# docker already have container running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I launch docker, it launch by default a few containers that I have build in the past.(I've use docker-compose at the time, but deleted the repo since)

I kill them, but each time i restart docker, they are back.
What can I do ?

I know there is something like "docker system prune",
but I would like to delete the less possible .

Answer (score 2):

You can try running `docker ps -a` to get a list of all containers including the ones which are not running but stopped.
You can then `docker rm` each container you do not wish to start on each docker restart.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `docker ps` to see what containers are running.
2. Use this command to kill/stop all running containers.

   docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
3. Use `docker images` to get list of all images.
4. Use `docker rmi <image_id>` to delete desired image.